# getline(3) keeps failing on loop after receiving signal SIGINT (Ctrl+C)

Tags: c

When `getline()` is waiting for user input, upon receiving the signal SIGINT it returns an error. However, in the next calls to `getline()`, it keeps returning the error, even though no other signal has been sent.

Here is a minimalized example of the problem:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

static void sig_handler(int signo) {
    fprintf(stderr, "SIGINT DETECTED\n");
}

int main(void) {
    struct sigaction sa;
    sigset_t smask;
    sigemptyset(&smask);
    sa.sa_handler = sig_handler;
    sa.sa_mask = smask;
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);

    while (1) {
        printf("Write something.\n");
        char *line = NULL;
        size_t buflen = 0;
        int res = getline(&line, &buflen, stdin);

        if (res == -1) {
            perror("getline()");
            free(line);
            continue;
        }

        printf("%s", line);
        free(line);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I would expect that `getline()` would fail after receiving the signal (the program would print the error) but when the loop restarts it would ask again "Write something." and wait for the user input.

However, after a single SIGINT signal, the `getline()` will always fail (it doesn't wait for user input) and the program will be stuck on an infinite loop:

```
Write something.
getline(): Interrupted system call
Write something.
getline(): Interrupted system call
Write something.
getline(): Interrupted system call
Write something.
getline(): Interrupted system call
...
```

How can I "clear" the error caused by SIGINT in `getline()` so that the program doesn't get stuck on an infinite loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You practically answered your own question with the phrase "clear the error": you need to call [`clearerr(stdin)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/clearerr) before retrying the `getline`.

(Unrelated issue: it is generally not safe to call library functions like `fprintf` inside a signal handler, especially when in this case the handler may run while inside another library function.  Standard library functions are not guaranteed to be reentrant unless specifically stated.)

Comment: Reentrancy is not the only requirement for a function to be async-signal-safe.  Strictly speaking, reentrancy does not require thread safety, but an async-signal-safe function has to be both reentrant and thread-safe.  [The C11 standard puts it this way](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note188): "Thus, a signal handler cannot, in general, call standard library functions."  The only functions that can be safely called from within a signal handler have to be specified by the implementation as a platform-specific extension to C.

Comment: (cont) The POSIX list of async-signal-safe functions can be found [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04) (page down a bit...)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to resume the read system call, you need to set `SA_RESTART` flag.

You're currently clearing it:

```
sa.sa_flags = 0;
```

Instead, do:

```
sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
```

Comment: That would be a little different than what I think OP has in mind.  That will result in `getline` not failing at all.  I understood what OP wants is that it should fail once, but then succeed on the next iteration of the loop.